# SELECT ... FOR UPDATE returns old value after waiting for lock

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, mysql-5.7

It seems that if `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` has to wait for a lock, and meanwhile another thread changes what would be the result, and commits, then the initial query returns the *old* result, i.e. from *before* the change.

Is this expected behavior or a bug? It certainly does not seem useful.

It is easy to demonstrate. Let's take the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orders`(  
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And this sequence of statements:

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
BEGIN;

SELECT MAX(id)
FROM orders
FOR UPDATE;

# PAUSE HERE

INSERT INTO orders (description)
VALUES ('bla');

COMMIT;
```

Now we do the following:

1. Open two connections.
2. On connection 1, execute up to the pause. This succeeds.
3. On connection 2, execute up to the pause. This gets stuck waiting for a lock.
4. On connection 1, execute the rest. This succeeds.
5. **Connection 2 has now returned the *previous* id!**
6. On connection 2, execute the `SELECT` once more. *Now* it returns the updated value.

So to get behavior that seems sensible and desirable, it seems that we are forced to execute the `SELECT` twice.

Is this expected behavior or a bug?

(Tested on MySQL 5.7.25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the explanation for the behavior, by doing some experiments. I have used connection 1 to perform some other changes rather than insert a new row. The combined results reveal how the process works.

- If connection 1 updates the `description` for the `id`, connection 2 will see the updated `description`. (The index scan has halted before the locked row.)
- If connection 1 updates the `id` to a *smaller*  value, e.g. from 10 to 9, connection 2 will return the new value, 9. (The index scan has halted before the locked row, sees it disappear, and continues in a descending manner, thus arriving at 9.)
- If connection 1 updates the `id` to a *greater* value, e.g. from 10 to 11, connection 2 will *skip that value* and instead return the greatest `id` that is smaller than what its original value was. In this example, it returns `id` 9 if that exists. (The index scan has halted before the locked row, sees it disappear, and continues in a descending manner, thus never passing 11, but rather arriving at 9.)
- If connection 1 updates the `id` to a greater value, e.g. from 10 to 11, and then inserts a new row in place of the old one, e.g. with `id` 10, connection 2 will select the newly inserted row. (The index scan has halted before the locked row, and will see something inserted in its place.)
- TODO: If connection 1 updates the `id` to a greater value, e.g. from 10 to 20, and then inserts a new row in place of the old one, but with a greater value than the original, e.g. 11, will connection 2 see it? Most likely not, but this should be tested.
- If connection 1 locks a `MAX(id)` of 10, and connection 2 selects a hard-coded `id` of 9, then the locks do not overlap, and both can proceed independently.

We can conclude that the `MAX(id)` is determined using a reverse scan, and that the locks  are on actual (index) rows. This makes sense. Our isolation level of `READ COMMITTED` does not acquire gap locks. `REPEATABLE READ` might, but it causes the transaction of connection 2 to fail entirely, so there is no exploring that scenario any deeper.

**Concluding the exact workings**

> Connection 2 starts reverse scanning until it hits a lock on a certain row.
>
> It will wait for that lock to be released, and continue its scan *from (and including) whatever `id` it left off at*. Not whatever *row*, but whatever *`id`*.

- As a result, if there is no longer a row at that `id`, the scan continues beyond it, to smaller `id`s.
- As a result, if the row has been updated, the updated values are visible (if selecting more than just the *id*).
- As a result, if the row has been moved and a new one inserted for its *id*, that new row is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. If you've started a select query, you want those results to be consistent to the start of that query (or transaction).  Because you're specifying FOR UPDATE, you're indicating the start of a transaction.  When you commit that's the end of your transaction, which is why step 6 returns the updated value.

If another session updates a row that is involved in your select and commits it, your session uses rollback data to reconstruct the data as of the start time of your transaction.

Comment: Right. So I want to get the value at the time I have _acquired_ the lock - the value that I know is not going to be changed by another process, since I now have the lock. Is issuing the `SELECT` once more the way to go about this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any complexity to simply do

```
INSERT ...;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is held in the connection, so it is impervious to any other actions going on.

Why do you need `MAX(id)`?

Case 1:  You will use it in some other insert.  Then the transaction is perfectly fine *this* way:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT ...;
SELECT @id := LAST_INSERT_ID();  -- and put into local variable or @variable
INSERT something else ... VALUES (..., @id, ...);
COMMIT;
```

Case 2:  Well, explain your case.

Comment: Here is the case: Multiple instances of a process will insert items. The real primary key is more like `name, sequence_number`. For a certain name, the process adds contiguous sequence numbers. Auto-increment is not satisfactory, because the sequence numbers are on a per-name basis (among other reasons). The instances of the process must not interfere. So one gets the greatest existing sequence number for a given name, write-locking it. It then inserts the next sequence. Once it completes, the next process may acquire the lock, continuing where the previous left off.

Comment: @Timo - That is a different scenario from what your question asked -- It specifically had an auto_inc as the PK.  I suggest you abandon this Q&A (since it has some discussion) and start a new Question _with the details you just mentioned_!

Comment: I see your point. In any case, perhaps you could still answer the main question from a general perspective: To get the `MAX(id)` value _after_ acquiring the lock (assuming the previous lock owner has changed it), is there another way than performing an extra `SELECT`?

Comment: @Timo - `LAST_INSERT_ID` does not need to go to the server; it is held with the connection.